# Check if vscode loaded js files dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on some extension for vscode. In this extension I use the `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` command. In order for this function to return the value for my extension, I need to wait until test workspace is "loaded"/"indexed" so this would work with JS files and imports in them. Also you need to open a file from the workspace so it could start this "loading". I want to know for sure if it loaded everything it needs after opening a workspace so I could safely trigger the `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` command. Does vscode have some kind of flag/event that indicates if workspace is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

With `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider`, VS Code's built-in JS/TS support will only return a result once it has loaded and processed that file. If the target file is part of a `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.jon` project, that means that the project will have been fully loaded. The definitions you expect should be returned

If however the targeted file is just a loose file, then `vscode.executeDefinitionProvider` may not return the expected results. There is no way to force the entire "project" to be loaded in these cases.

This behavior should generally be true for other language as well, but this is not guaranteed